# The two classes "fa fa-commenting" and "fa fa-user-plus" don't work

Tags: html, css, class, icons, show

I'm trying to display some icons in a page I've created. The problem is that when I put the two lines below in my code, the commenting icon and the user add icon can't be displayed:

```
<i class="fa fa-commenting"></i>
<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
```

By the way, you can have a look at the two links below to have an idea about what the commenting icon and the user add icon that I'm trying to display are :

The commenting icon:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/commenting/

The user add icon:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/user-plus/

However, if I put the two lines below:

```
<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
```

the times circle icon and the exclamation triangle icon show on my computer screen without any problem. So, my question is: what is wrong with the two classes "fa fa-commenting" and "fa fa-user-plus"? Is there any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share Demo on jsfiddle or etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using latest, up to date version of Font Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use the entire font awesome archive content.

Do not just copy the font-awesome.css or font-awesome-min.css to your project.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the css files, make sure to replace all font in the webfonts Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you use another font for commenting like

```
 <i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>

 <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
```

Comment: No, I haven't. It's the same font.

Comment: Yes this is same font for commenting,you can also try this.